# How to set AWS_PROFILE in .bashrc? The config profile (/home/miki/.aws/config) could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services

My intention is to set permanently my AWS profile. I edited my .bashrc by adding this line

```
export AWS_PROFILE="$HOME/.aws/config"
```

`aws configure list`
shows error

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 337, in get_scoped_config
    raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (/home/miki/.aws/config) could not be found
```

But I can see it in .aws

```
~/.aws$ ll
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  2 miki miki 4096 Mar 11 09:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 40 miki miki 4096 Mar 22 12:53 ../
-rw-------  1 miki miki  104 Mar 22 12:03 config
-rw-------  1 miki miki  349 Mar 11 10:14 credentials
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AWS_PROFILE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) is not for path such as `$HOME/.aws/config`. It is for [named profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html).

If you want to set config and credentials file paths you should use `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` and `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE`.